# Accessing same key:value pair in list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

In python, I have a list cities which contains approximately 12 dictionaries, each containing 4 key:value pairs in the exact same place for each dictionary.   How do i access or print the same value pair in each dictionary?

Comment: Please post your code. Without that, it is very difficult for anyone to help.

Comment: You exhibit no effort into solving this and no data for us to work either.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To clarify, are you saying there are the same 4 keys in all 12 dictionaries?

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post [a minimal example of what needs to change](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the name of key (in key value paris in dictionary), you can just loop in the list and print it directly .For example :
below if a list of 2 dictionary where we know there are key: 1,2,3
and we are printing the value directly:

```python
city=[
    {1:'bhopal', 2:'newyork', 3:'italy'},
    {1:'london', 2:'india', 3:'europe'}
]

for i in city:
    print(i[1]), i[2] , i[3])

for i in city:
    for key,value in i.items():
         print (key,value)
```

I hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

Since keys of your dictionaries are always the same you could iterate over all elements of your list and print value corresponding to specific key you choosed.

```
cities = [
    {'population': 1000,
    'name': 'Oslo',
    'size': 12513200,
    'temperature': 2},
    {'population': 20000,
    'name': 'Chongqing',
    'size': 412400000,
    'temperature': 15},
    {'population': 1000,
    'name': 'Shanghai',
    'size': 5512332,
    'temperature': 33}
]

def print_specific(d, k):
    print(*[i[k] for i in d], sep='\n')

print_specific(cities, 'name')
```

**Output**

```
Oslo
Chongqing
Shanghai
```

Comment: How to store them in a separate list?

Comment: `return [i[k] for i in d]` instead of printing the names

Answer (score 0):

I write an example with nation seeing that I don't know your code (ps all the data are fake):

> dic={'uk':{'capital':'london', 'dimension':235423,
>   'population':31321}, 'france':{'capital':'paris', 'dimension':43523,
>   'population':542342}, 'italy':{'capital':'rome', 'dimension':935123,
>   'population':4323342}}

if you want take just the main nation just do:

```
dic.keys()
```

this will five you

```
['france', 'italy, 'uk']
```

if you want all the information about a nation dynamically you can do:

```
k=dic.keys()
for i in k:
    print dic[i]
```

Output:

```
{'population': 4323342, 'dimension': 935123, 'capital': 'rome'} 
{'population': 31321, 'dimension': 235423, 'capital': 'london'} 
{'population': 542342, 'dimension': 43523, 'capital': 'paris'}
```

If you want some specific information just add the specific node on the print:

```
k=dic.keys()
for i in k:
    print dic[i]['capital']
```

Output:

```
rome
london
paris
```

If instead you have a list of dictionary you can just iterate that and take the needed value:

> l=[{'population': 4323342, 'dimension': 935123, 'capital': 'rome'},
>   {'population': 31321, 'dimension': 235423, 'capital': 'london'},
>   {'population': 542342, 'dimension': 43523, 'capital': 'paris'}]

```
for i in l:
    print i['capital']
```

Output:

```
rome 
london 
paris
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not make a custom class for this?

```
class CustomMap(object):
    def __init__(self, *maps):
        self.maps = maps

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        found = []
        for mapping in self.maps:
            if mapping.get(key):
                found.append(mapping.get(key))
            else:
                continue
        return found

    def get(self, key):
        return self.__getitem__(key)

d = {'a': 2, 'b': 3}
e = {'a': 5, 'f': 1}

c = CustomMap(d, e)

c['a']
[2, 5]

c.get('a')
[2, 5]
```